# afterTextChange in TextWatcher how handle backspace and setText()?

Tags: android, user-interface, text, android-edittext

I have an EditText and  I use `afterTextChange()` to get values for every character, character by character. Well I have a button to do `editText.setText("")` but when I use that I get this error

> `charAt: 0 >= length 0.`

How can I handle this error and how can I handle backspace?

My code is :

```
 @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


                enigmaCoding(String.valueOf(s.charAt(ii)));
                ii++;

            }

        });


  public void restart(View view) {

        ii = 0;
        txtV.setText("");
        etxtC.setText("");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check

```
if(s!=null && s.toString().length()>0)
{
  currentLength = s.toString().length();
  if(currentLength < previousLength){
      --ii;
  }else{
     enigmaCoding(String.valueOf(s.charAt(ii)));
     ii++;
 }
    previousLength = currentLength;// store previous length
}
```

Comment: tnx man it work for setText(""), how cah i handel backSpace , when i use backSpace i have this error charAt: 7 >= length 6 @N J

Comment: still charAt: 5 >= length 4 @N J
and when i use space , it parint the last char i use in another textView

Comment: Edited answer again

Comment: it work when delet , and when type again have this error charAt: 1 >= length 1@ N J